# Get all pairs of supplier numbers such that two suppliers are colocated

Tags: sql, select, db2

the exercise is:
Get all pairs of supplier numbers such that two suppliers are colocated

The output should be

```
SA   SB
---  ---
S2   S3
S1   S4
```

and here is that Table:

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers 



SNO   SNAME      STATUS CITY       
----- ---------- ------ ---------- 
S1    Smith          20 London     
S2    Jones          10 Paris      
S3    Blake          30 Paris      
S4    Clark          20 London     
S5    Adams          30 Athens
```

5 record(s) selected.

Comment: My mistake was that i tried select DISTINCT s1.SNO SA, s2.SNO SB from suppliers s1, suppliers s2 where s1.CITY = s2.CITY AND s1.SNO != s2.SNO; but got multiple pairs. I didnt think of Mureiniks answer with "smaller" one @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could self-join the table on the `city` column. To avoid duplicate pairs (e.g., s2-s3 and s3-s2), add a condition that the first one should always be the "smaller" one:

```
SELECT a.sno AS sa, b.sno AS sb
FROM   suppliers a
JOIN   suppliers b ON a.city = b.city AND a.sno < b.sno
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, perfekt answer